# How can we achieve following scenario in Workflow?

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation

Following is the exact scenario in my application

[image]

this may be appearing a very basic question.. but I am relatively quite new in Workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe a bit too late, but you could use the **SendActivity** in your workflow to call the WCF services, along with an **IfElseActivity** for deciding what to do based on the user's ID.

Also, it would be overkill to use WF for this type of scenario, unless there's more to it that your question portrays.